# connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, database-connection

I have build the next js project
I have tried to open MySQL database with phpmyadmin and it is opening fine and created a database
with database user and password

but on the website tried with the same credential database call gets connection refused error

**error : connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306**

**already checked tried**

recheck username and password

MySQL server running status on nginx server

tried to change host:localhost to 127.0.0.1

tried to change host:localhost to server IP address

**here is my db connection code**

```
import { createPool } from "mysql2";

const pool = createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  port: 3306,
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 500, // max idle connections, the default value is the same as `connectionLimit`
  connectTimeout: 60000, // idle connections timeout, in milliseconds, the default value 60000
  queueLimit: 10,
});

pool.getConnection((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Database Didn't connected!!!");
  }
  console.log("Database Connected....");
});
```

connection running

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

some editional info

I have configured multiple site on same sever with nginx site-available
I am new to web development so I am providing as much as I know
let me know if anything other info required to spot the issue

Comment: Do you still get the same `ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306` error even after changing the host to `127.0.0.1`, or is the error different?

Comment: Could there be a fire wall getting in the way